# Build a table from SQLite query with Loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, electron

## Introduction

At my company, we currently use Excel to maintain a rather large database of items that is used for cost estimation.

I am building an Electron App to replace that with a simple database and some more user friendly forms and reports.

Right now, I have a SQLite db that contains 2 tables:

```
materials
walls
```

There are going to be more added at some point. Rather than adding the table html for each table that is added, I want to loop through the data and build the tables dynamically.

Here is a screenshot of what the app should look like (using pre-coded columns):

[image: 1]

### What I've gotten to work:

I loop through the 'sqlite_master' table to get the names of each table for the menu on the left. Then I use each table name (row.name) to call another function that gets the column names for each table, which I then input to the table, so I get this:

[image: 2]]

### Where i'm struggling:

After I get this far, I need to loop through the table and display it in the right pane. If I already know the column names, I can pre-code this and loop through each row, but I need to be able to dynamically add/remove columns and tables (similar to an excel workbook) so pre-coding them just isn't an option.

### What I THINK I need to do:

I always hate this part, because I know just enough to screw up.

I think I need to get a list of each column, then add a line similar to

```
let rowInfo = "<td>" + {{colName}} + "</td>" //WHERE THIS WOULD BE A LIST OF ALL COLS
for (i = 0; i <= col.length; i++) {
    $("#tableRows").append(rowInfo);
}
```

But I don't know how to get from here to there.

### Relevant Code Snippets:

```
function getMaterials() { // This is what I use to get the data from Image 1
    let sqlite3 = require( 'sqlite3' ).verbose();
    let db      = new sqlite3.Database( 'quoteTemplate.db' );

    db.each( "SELECT * FROM materials", function ( err, row ) {
        let table        = document.getElementById( "materialsTable" );
        let tableRow     = table.insertRow( 0 );
        let cell1        = tableRow.insertCell( 0 );
        let cell2        = tableRow.insertCell( 1 );
        let cell3        = tableRow.insertCell( 2 );
        let cell4        = tableRow.insertCell( 3 );
        let cell5        = tableRow.insertCell( 4 );
        let cell6        = tableRow.insertCell( 5 );
        let cell7        = tableRow.insertCell( 6 );
        let cell8        = tableRow.insertCell( 7 );
        let cell9        = tableRow.insertCell( 8 );
        let cell10       = tableRow.insertCell( 9 );
        let cell11       = tableRow.insertCell( 10 );
        let cell12       = tableRow.insertCell( 11 );
        cell1.innerHTML  = row.id;
        cell2.innerHTML  = row.item;
        cell3.innerHTML  = row.material;
        cell4.innerHTML  = row.type;
        cell5.innerHTML  = row.price;
        cell6.innerHTML  = row.freight;
        cell7.innerHTML  = row.width;
        cell8.innerHTML  = row.length;
        cell9.innerHTML  = row.height;
        cell10.innerHTML = row.thickness;
        cell11.innerHTML = row.weight;
        cell12.innerHTML = row.weightper;
    } );

    db.close();
}

function getTablesList() { // This gets the tables for the left pane
    let sqlite3 = require( 'sqlite3' ).verbose();
    let db      = new sqlite3.Database( 'quoteTemplate.db' );
    let list    = $( "#tablesList" );

    db.each( "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'lorem'", function ( err, row ) {
        let activeChk = "";
        if(row.name == 'materials') {
            activeChk = "active";
        }
        list.append( '<span class="nav-group-item ' + activeChk + ' " onclick="getName(\'' + row.name + '\')">' + row.name + "</span>" );
    } );

    db.close();
}

function getName( table ) { // This gets the header row
    let sqlite3         = require( 'sqlite3' ).verbose();
    let db              = new sqlite3.Database( 'quoteTemplate.db' );
    let mainTableHeader = document.getElementById( "materialsTableHeader" );

    $( "#materialsTableHeader tr" ).remove();
    $( "#materialsTable tr" ).remove();
    let tableHeaderRow = mainTableHeader.insertRow( 0 );

    db.each( "PRAGMA table_info('" + table + "')", function ( err, row ) {
        let cell       = tableHeaderRow.insertCell( 0 );
        cell.outerHTML = "<th>" + row.name + "</th>";
    } );

    db.close();

    getRows( table );
}

function getRows( tableName ) { // This is where I want to get the table data
    let sqlite3   = require( 'sqlite3' ).verbose();
    let db        = new sqlite3.Database( 'quoteTemplate.db' );
    let mainTable = document.getElementById( "materialsTable" );

    // I need the code that would go here

    db.close();
}
```

As always, any advice is more than appreciated. I realize I am probably asking something basic, but isn't that how it always goes? We can excel (ha!) in the difficult things like building complex user interfaces, but we brainfart on the easy things.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I figured it out...

```
function getRows( tableName ) {
    let sqlite3   = require( 'sqlite3' ).verbose();
    let db        = new sqlite3.Database( 'quoteTemplate.db' );
    let mainTable = document.getElementById( "materialsTable" );
    db.each( 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName, [], function ( tx, results ) {
        let tableRow = mainTable.insertRow( 0 );
        $.each(results, function(key, value){
            let cell       = tableRow.insertCell( 0 );
            cell.outerHTML = "<td>" + value + "</td>";
        });
    } );
    db.close();
}
```

I knew it was something simple.